# Java Content-MD5 Header mismatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, md5

I am trying to send content from a file to the Amazon db. The MD5 hash I generated doesn't fit the one Amazon generates. What am I doing wrong?

```
  try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("upload.txt");                
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] buffer=new byte[8192];
        int read=0;
        while( (read = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                md.update(buffer, 0, read);
        byte[] md5 = md.digest();
        BigInteger bi=new BigInteger(1, md5);
        String output = bi.toString(16);
        System.out.println(output);
        SubmitFeed.submit(fis, output);
} catch(Exception e) { 
  // removed: not relevant to question
}
```

The hash amazon reports me back seems to have a different pattern.

mine: ...5856911dca2be1...

amazon: ...AmY7PhCfg==

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Amazon hash is using base64, whereas you're using hex. If you use a base64 library ([such as this one](http://iharder.net/base64)) you should be okay. (I can't validate that with the values in your post, as they're incomplete. I'd be amazed if it didn't work though.)

(I'd also suggest *not* using `BigInteger` as a way of converting binary to hex. It happens to be able to do that, modulo leading zeroes, but it's not its purpose.)

Comment: thx, I think Im a step further right now. I pass the error and run into another one. "Service Error. Response Status: 400. Received message: Bad Request" this time :( Im not sure if this relates to a wron md5 sum.